# If there's no relation between $c_1$ and $c_2$, can I say that $c_1= r\sin \theta,c_2=r\cos \theta$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

If there's no relation between $c_1$ and $c_2$, can I say that $c_1= r\sin \theta,c_2=r\cos \theta$?

In other words, does the following system in the variables $r,\theta$, always have solution?

$$
r\sin\theta = c \\
r\cos \theta = d
$$

This question comes from some notes I'm reading on differential equations, where they use this to simplify these expressions:

$$
y_1=c_1\cos\beta t+c_2\sin\beta t = r\cos(\theta-\beta t)\\
y_2=-c_1\sin\beta t+c_2\cos \beta t= r\sin (\theta - \beta t)
$$

Comment: It's actually $c_1^2+c_2^2=r^2$, doesn't that help?

Comment: It's just changing Cartesian to polar coordinates.

Comment: yes: $r=\sqrt{c^2+d^2},\tan \theta=\frac{c}{d}$

Comment: Yes, you can do that. And if $r$ is restricted to be $\ge 0$, and $\theta$ ranges over the interval $[0,2\pi)$ then $r$ and $\theta$ are uniquely determined, except $\theta$ is not determined if $r=0$. Look up *polar coordinates*.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Damn... I know polar coordinates, I had a bit of a brain lag, exams coming soon and I'm pretty tired, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can since the only consequence of such a system is that

$c^{2} + d^{2} =r^{2}$  and 
$\tan(\theta) = c/d$

for some arbitrary number $r$ and some angle $\theta$, assuming $c$ and $d$ have been given.

Such a number $r$ and such an angle $\theta$ always exist.

Answer (score 2):

If $c_1=c_2=0$ then $r=0$ and $\theta$ can be anything.

For other values of $c_1,c_2$ there will be many solutions, but it is often convenient to assume
$$r>0\ ,\qquad -\pi<\theta\le\pi\ ,$$
in which case there will be exactly one solution.  We have
$$r=\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}$$
and
$$\tan\theta=\frac{c_1}{c_2}$$
provided $c_2\ne0$.  By finding the sign of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ you can determine which quadrant $\theta$ is in, then this last equation gives you one definite value for $\theta$.  Finally, in the case $c_2=0$ we have
$$\theta=\begin{cases}\frac\pi2&\hbox{if}\ c_1>0\\ -\frac\pi2&\hbox{if}\ c_1<0.\end{cases}$$